# Code First One to Many Podendo ser nulo

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, code-first

Meu cenário:

```
 public class AlunoAvaliacao
    {
        public int AlunoAvaliacaoID { get; set; }
        public DateTime Inicio { get; set; }
        public DateTime? Fim { get; set; }
        public virtual int AvaliacaoID { get; set; }
        public virtual Avaliacao Avaliacao { get; set; }
        public virtual int AlunoID { get; set; }
        public virtual Aluno Aluno { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<AlunoAvaliacaoPergunta> AlunoAvaliacaoPerguntas { get; set; }
    }

public class AlunoAvaliacaoPergunta
    {
        public int AlunoAvaliacaoPerguntaID { get; set; }
        public virtual int AlunoAvaliacaoID { get; set; }
        public virtual AlunoAvaliacao AlunoAvaliacao { get; set; }
        public virtual int AvaliacaoPerguntaID { get; set; }
        public virtual AvaliacaoPergunta AvaliacaoPergunta { get; set; }

        public string Resposta { get; set; }
        public bool Correta { get; set; }
    }

        var alunoAvaliacao = new AlunoAvaliacao();
        alunoAvaliacao.Aluno = aluno;
        alunoAvaliacao.Avaliacao = avaliacao;
        alunoAvaliacao.Inicio = DateTime.Now;
        alunoAvaliacao.AlunoAvaliacaoPerguntas = new List<AlunoAvaliacaoPergunta>();
        bdAlunoAvaliacao.Adicionar(alunoAvaliacao);
        bdAlunoAvaliacao.SalvarTodos();
```

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in
>   EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: An object of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[Aplicacao.Core.Dominio.AvaliacaoPergunta,
>   Aplicacao.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null]]' cannot be set or removed from the Value
>   property of an EntityReference of type
>   'Aplicacao.Core.Dominio.AvaliacaoPergunta'.

Já tentei `modelBuilder`... E nada. Por que deste erro?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Há algumas coisas erradas. Vou discutir uma a uma aqui.

### 1. Procure anotar as chaves primárias com `[Key]`

Sabemos que o Entity Framework é bastante esperto para deduzir as chaves do *Model*, mas ainda considero importante para a legibilidade e organização da camada de *Models* anotar o atributo que é a chave primária para a tabela em banco de dados.

```
public class AlunoAvaliacao
{
    [Key]
    public int AlunoAvaliacaoID { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

### 2. Chaves estrangeiras não devem ser `virtual`

Ao contrário das propriedades de navegação, cujo uso do `virtual` é encorajado, o mesmo não deve ocorrer com propriedades que representem valores primitivos. A justificativa é que não vejo como necessário derivar um `int`, por exemplo. Para representação, `int` serve bem ao propósito de representar a chave estrangeira.

No mais, inserir `virtual` numa primitiva pode criar um complicador para o Entity Framework. Ou seja, procure elencar suas chaves estrangeiras sem `virtual` e logo abaixo da chave primária:

```
public class AlunoAvaliacao
{
    [Key]
    public int AlunoAvaliacaoID { get; set; }
    public int AvaliacaoID { get; set; }
    public int AlunoID { get; set; }

    ...
}

public class AlunoAvaliacaoPergunta
{
    [Key]
    public int AlunoAvaliacaoPerguntaID { get; set; }
    public int AlunoAvaliacaoID { get; set; }
    public int AvaliacaoPerguntaID { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

### 3. Observe a mensagem de erro

Repare que a mensagem de erro fala o seguinte:

> An object of type **'System.Collections.Generic.List`1**[[Aplicacao.Core.Dominio.AvaliacaoPergunta, Aplicacao.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]' cannot be set or removed from the Value property of an **EntityReference of type 'Aplicacao.Core.Dominio.AvaliacaoPergunta'**.

Você está atribuindo uma lista do tipo `IList<AvaliacaoPergunta>` em um objeto unitário, provavelmente este:

```
public class AlunoAvaliacaoPergunta
{
    ...
    public virtual AvaliacaoPergunta AvaliacaoPergunta { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

O código colocado na pergunta não esclarece o que está acontecendo, mas em algum lugar, `AvaliacaoPergunta` está recebendo esta `IList<AvaliacaoPergunta>`.

No final, seus *Models* deveriam ficar assim:

```
public class AlunoAvaliacao
{
    [Key]
    public int AlunoAvaliacaoID { get; set; }
    public int AvaliacaoID { get; set; }
    public int AlunoID { get; set; }

    public DateTime Inicio { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Fim { get; set; }

    public virtual Avaliacao Avaliacao { get; set; }
    public virtual Aluno Aluno { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<AlunoAvaliacaoPergunta> AlunoAvaliacaoPerguntas { get; set; }
}

public class AlunoAvaliacaoPergunta
{
    [Key]
    public int AlunoAvaliacaoPerguntaID { get; set; }
    public int AlunoAvaliacaoID { get; set; }
    public int AvaliacaoPerguntaID { get; set; }

    public string Resposta { get; set; }
    public bool Correta { get; set; }

    public virtual AlunoAvaliacao AlunoAvaliacao { get; set; }
    public virtual AvaliacaoPergunta AvaliacaoPergunta { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Descobri que eu estava fazendo um negocio muito errado... Valeu pelas correções Cigano, alem do Key, é bom adicionar os ForeignKey, tambem né?

Comment: `ForeignKey` não precisa. É comum usarem essa anotação errado, e ela muda radicalmente o comportamento do *Model*.